# CAML query to fetch a specific row

Tags: excel, soap, sharepoint, vba

I am using Excel VBA to fetch SharePoint list using SOAP requests.

I am able to fetch all records.

How can I fetch a Name with specific Roll Number?

Below is the Excel VBA code snippet.

```
Public Function retrieveSharepoint()
Dim currentId As String, ACP As String, DL As String
Dim returnedRow As Object
Dim setNode As Object
Dim sURL As String
    Dim sEnv As String
    Dim xmlhtp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim xmlDoc As New DOMDocument60
    sURL = "https://sites.com/sites/project/project_ext/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"
    sEnv = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap12=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">"
    sEnv = sEnv & "  <soap12:Body>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "    <GetListItems xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"">"
    sEnv = sEnv & "         <listName>{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx}</listName>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "    </GetListItems>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "  </soap12:Body>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "</soap12:Envelope>"

    With xmlhtp
        .Open "post", sURL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
        .setRequestHeader "soapAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems"
        .send sEnv
        xmlDoc.LoadXML (.responseText)
        For Each returnedRow In .responseXML.getElementsByTagName("z:row")
            currentId = returnedRow.getAttribute("ows_Roll_x0020_Number")
            ACP = returnedRow.getAttribute("ows_Name")
            DL = returnedRow.getAttribute("ows_Last_x0020_Name")
        Next
        MsgBox .responseText
    End With

End Function
```

Currently I am able to fetch all records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Query` element:

/edit

Ok, I have checked with Postman and proper SOAP XML is for example:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <listName>{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx}</listName>
            <query>
                <Query>
                    <Where>
                        <Eq>
                            <FieldRef Name='ID' />
                            <Value Type='Number'>260</Value>
                        </Eq>
                    </Where>
                </Query>
            </query>
        </GetListItems>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So, your code should look like this:

```
sEnv = sEnv & "         <listName>{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx}</listName>"
sEnv = sEnv & "         <query><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Roll_x0020_Number' /><Value Type='Number'>#YOUR NUMBER#</Value></Eq></Where></Query></query>"
```

Additional reference: [Lists.GetListItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-services/ms772599(v=office.12))

Comment: I tried what you have mentioned, but no success.Instead, it fetches all records.

Comment: try `query` in lower case

Comment: I tried using a query in lowercase, it showed me all records.

Comment: look at my answer, i've checked with postman and changed it to `<query><Query>` last thursday

Comment: can you guide me how can I update Name column of a Roll Number, if possible

Comment: it's not possible to change internal name, display name can be changed from list settings.

Comment: I am not asking change of column name, but how can I update a "Name" field based on "Roll Number" field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166300/discussion-between-tinamou-and-rbk).

Comment: how can i retrieve data applying multiple criteria for eg: fetching "Roll Number" with the help of "Name" and "Last Name" fields